# Logging in with a fingerprint reader

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader

Sony Vaio VPCZ112GX has a built in fingerprint reader. I have fingerprint gui installed and it works everywhere else but does not even ask for it at login. Any idea why? I'm running Zorin 12.1 Ultimate which is based on the latest Ubuntu. Kinda new to Linux in general. Any help would be appreciated.